# Pasar datos desde Java a JavaScript con Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

Sería posible pasar información a la interfaz,desde una clase java sin utilizar JSP? Como un método push pero en la otra dirección. Todo esto con Thymeleaf.
En un principio he pensado en pasar esta información como parámetros en la URL y recuperarlos, pero con el arquetipo usado esta opción queda descartada.

La a aplicación añade registros a una tabla SQLServer y la idea era poder mandar estos registros como cadena a la interfaz HTML, pudiendo sacarlos en una ventana, a modo de consola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola disculpa por no responde antes, para recuperar en la vista debes hacer algo asi.

pongamos el ejemplo Prueba

tiene un atributo   Private Integer nota;

entonces tu recuperas el valor de esta forma

```
${prueba.nota}


<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                            <label for="name">Nota</label>
                            <input type="text"   th:value="${prueba.nota}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acabo de aplicar esto a mi programa y ha funcionado correctamente. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente, que bueno haber ayudado..!

Answer (score 1):

cuando usas Thymeleaf, las paginas son .html no jsp, hay varias formas de pasar información a la vista, puedes se con un objeto json, o con el objeto Model de Spring, todo depende de que forma estas llamando a tu controlador.

Cuando usas la clase model es algo asi.

```
Model model; 
Prueba  prueba =  new Prueba();
model.addAttribute("prueba", prueba );
```

esta clase model permite pasar todo tipo de datos, de primitivos a objetos complejos, funciona como una especie de HashMap().

espero ayudar saludos

Comment: Parece una solución bastante sencilla y rápida de realizar. ¿Cómo recupero esa variable "prueba" en la vista?

Comment: Hola disculpa por no responde antes, para recuperar en la vista debes hacer algo asi.

pongamos el ejemplo Prueba

tiene un atributo   Private Integer nota;

entonces tu recuperas el valor de esta forma


${prueba.nota}